# Returning the number of characters in a file (universally)

Tags: python

I'm working on my weekly assignment in my intro to Python class.
We have a file ( planets.txt ) and we have to write a function to return the number of characters in the file.
I have written a function to do so, and the value is accurate. But my teaching team says that the code is not "universal" (?) and will not work with other files. I don't understand this at all.

My code is:

```
def num_chars_in_file(file):
    path = 'planets.txt'
    file_handle = open(path)
    planetstxt = file_handle.read()
    count = 0

    for text in planetstxt:
        count += len(text)

    file_handle.close()

    return count

print(f"\nProblem 1: {num_chars_in_file('path')}")
```

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with it? What does universal code mean?

Comment: Given that `file_handle.read()` returns a string, `len(text)` is always 1

Comment: Simple, `planets.txt` is in the code of your function.

Comment: You can just do `len(file_handle.read())` directly

Comment: @Maarten  good call :)

Comment: Now try calling it with the name of a different text file

Comment: Why not just asking them?

Comment: So I changed it to len(file_handle.read()). But I'm not sure what else to do. How do I not include the path = 'planets.txt' ?

Comment: It is better to ask your teaching team as @ShayaUlman suggested. Also the problem description is vague in your question. What is a "character"? You are counting the spaces and newlines in your code too. Do they count as characters?

Comment: The reason why it is not working universally is because the variable read as a parameter 'file' is never used for enumerating file length. for that purpose the variable 'path' is used, which is statically set to path pointing still to the same file no matter what you pass as a parameter ;)

Comment: @Selcuk yes they're counting spaces and newlines. I originally used an rsplit to not count them, but the correct value includes them for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your code working on other files (=universally), you need it to be dynamic.
Instead of hard coding the file name, pass it as an argument:

```py
def num_chars_in_file(file):
    file_handle = open(file)
    ...

num_chars_in_file('some-file.txt')
```

Comment: Why would this work? You are not using the variable `file` anywhere.

Comment: @ShayaUlman So I am getting the correct value for the file in my situation. However, the function is not working 'universally'

Comment: @ShayaUlman Is the problem the " file = 'planets.txt' " ? does that need to be a dynamic variable? What should it look like if so?

Comment: `path` will now always be the file you pass in the function as an argument!

Comment: `path` should become the function argument. `path = file` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
def num_chars(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return sum([len(char.rstrip()) for char in f])

num_chars('test.txt')
```

Comment: Code only posts are not really considered answers.